# prevent double entries in friends Array

Tags: ios, objective-c

Im working on this project where i have users that can send contact information to to each other. The problem that i work on is to prevent my users from sending there contact information more than once. To send the contact information i use a UIButton. The users that are retrieving the contact information are listed in a TableView an the button i located in the users detail view. From the tableView i take the username, from the selected user an bring it in to the detail view. So i have the username. When the users pushes the button i want to store this name, and the, if the user push the button again, i want to check if this username is contained among the saved usernames. If not, i want to save the new user, if its already saved, i want nothing to happened.

In tableView.m, prepareForSegue i get the username like this.

```
PFObject *object = [self.objects objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
FindCell *find = [[FindCell alloc] init];
find.userId = [object objectForKey:@"username"];
destViewController.find= find;
```

The username is stored like this in my cell.h

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *userId; // username
```

And then i get the username to my detailsView.m.

```
- (IBAction)addCard

- (BOOL)added
```

And from here i run i don´t get it to work. I don´t know how to set this up in an efficient way. I have seen lost of example that i have tried, but non of them works the way i need to do this. Those anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Is self.objects your array?

Comment: Instead of array, you can go for NSSet. In NSSet you always have a unique entry for item.

Comment: `@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *friends` Is my array. And find.userId my new objects (or old) i have tried the NSet but i dont get how to set this up in my IBAction, how do i construct the If or else statement?

Comment: While adding element to array, just give a "if conditon" to check if its already present. Juz check option 2 in my ans. Hope this will help you. Happy Coding!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Option 1**

You can use NSSet to get array having only unique elements

```
NSSet *uniqueSet = [[NSSet alloc] initWithArray:yourArray];
NSArray *uniqueElementsArray = [uniqueSet allObjects];
```

**Option 2**

Check if element is already present in array, if not add to array

```
   if ([yourArray containsObject:element])
   {
       //Don't add to array
   } 
   else
   {
       //add to array
       [yourArray addObject:element];
   }
```

Comment: Okey! Nice! So if @property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *friends is "yourArray" and find.userId is my item, what is my element?

Comment: Jus check my answer!! There is no item, it was a typing mistake. If "find.userId" is the one going to array, you can consider it as element

Comment: Ah! okey! I try this then :)

Comment: Probably a noob thing but on addObject I get "No visible @Interface for NSArray declares the selector addObject". Do you know why?

Comment: Use NSMutableArray instead of NSArray.